# Is the php REQUIRE valid within a meta content head statement?

Tags: php, html, meta

I understand that including `<?php require("example.php"); ?>` inside an html document results in the file `example.php` being included ("as a literal string") at that point in the document.  e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head> .. </head>
    <body>
      <?php 
         require("example.php"); 
       ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

This works within the body of the html document but is it valid to use the same technique in a meta statement in the head e.g `<meta name="description" content="<?php require("example.php");?>">` ? 
Such a document displays fine but is such a meta tag working?

Comment: The browser is unaware of the PHP source code, so as long as it receives a valid `<meta . . .` tag after php is finished, it's irrelevant how it got there.

Comment: Yes this is fine. As long as your HTML has correct syntax, it doesn't matter how you generate it.

Comment: Though I'd use `require` inside the <head> section with a file that contains all the meta (or more) tags. I wouldn't go down the route of doing a require for a single attribute value.

Comment: CollinD, the PHP is inside the meta tag, inside the quotes of the content part.

Comment: Alex, the html is good so it should work.  Thanks

Comment: @talvi Please do some research on how server-side rendering works. It might help you to understand why the php being inside of the quotes isn't important.

Comment: Jon, I am in fact using the require more extensively (e.g for the top portion of the document including most of the head section).  The question related to using it for a portion of the head specific to each page the text of which repeats in a number of places on a document and in other linked documents. Thanks for your suggestion.  Appreciated.

Comment: @ColinD, I spotted some conditionality in your reply that suggested a possible error in my understanding (which doesn't appear to be the case so all is good).  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"*...including `<?php require("example.php"); ?>` inside an html document results in the file example.php being included ("as a literal string") at that point...*"

The very basis of your assumption is wrong. Files with `.html` extensions are not generally parsed by the php "compiler" (unless you are specifically making the server do so which is relatively advance technique for this question to exist). They are not even passed to php runtime, as your server delivers them right out of the box, bypassing the php execution flow altogether.

Since they aren't parsed, any php tags inside those files is just a string of character. So the require statement doesn't mean anything and which means the "required file" isn't included, neither as a literal string nor as a live code.

About it being valid within a meta tag, now since they(the php tags) aren't parsed the server will output that string exactly as is, so the validity will have to be determined in terms of html specification(Since there is no role for php to play whatsoever).

And in terms of HTML, the client side browser will try to interprete that php tag and most probably confuse it with an xml tag (`<?xml`), which btw is not valid **anywhere** inside an html document, neither in head nor in meta nor anywhere else.

Comment: My bad, all the files have `.php extensions`  fwiw the error is my not thinking of PHP files as being "documents", hence my confusing use of vocabulary.  Thanks for your answer and apologies for the mixup

Comment: @talvi You're welcome, and accepting the answer makes the gratitude waay more sweeter than thanking in comments :)